# i have shared service ,i inject dataSource!: MatTableDataSource i got undefined and can't reder

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-material

[enter image description here][1]i have Shared service , i create a method using MatTableDataSource to get requiset api from json server  and when i use this method into my components dataSource became undefined, and i can't renrder the data into HTML mtTable

```
[enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtxxV.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kusy.png
```

Comment: Share some block of code

Comment: hello Parth , https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtxxV.png

Answer (score 0):

I think for this approch you need to implement different logic then current one.
Change in service:

- Declare Behavioursubject in service and once data get after service
  call then .`next()` of behaviour subject
- In component onInit method set `subscribe()` method of
  behavioursubject which using service instant.
- Inside above subscribe() method find the change in data of service
  behaviour so you need to give data to datasource.